# Optimize right joins

Tags: sql, mysql

The following query is working as expected. But I guess there is enough room for optimization. Any help?

```
SELECT   a.cond_providentid,
      b.flag1
FROM     c_master a
WHERE    a.cond_status = 'OnService'
ORDER BY a.cond_providentid,
         a.rto_number;
```

Comment: why are you using `SUM()`? `SUM(1|0)` can be written without `SUM()` ;)

Comment: 16 questions and you won't grant answers?  No thanks...

Comment: If you use right join, you don't deserve an answer... just kidding

Comment: >> 16 questions and you won't grant answers? No thanks
I am sorry but I did not notice this. I will recheck all the questions and see to that I accept answers.

Comment: Go to the questions you have already asked, check the answers that people have taken time to provide, accept the answer that best answers your question - if no answers is relevant then try adding further details. You have asked 17 questions and still only accepted 1 - if you want community help then you must be part of the community and at least put in the effort to get to get your questions completed

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest placing the query within your left join in a database view - in that way, the code can be much more cleaner and easier to maintain.

Also, check the columns that you often use the most.. it could be a candidate for indexing so that when you run your query, it can be faster.

You also might check your column data types... I see that you have this type of code:

> (CASE
>               WHEN b.tray_type IS NULL
>               THEN 1
>               ELSE 0
>             END) flag2

If you have a chance to change the design for your tables, (i.e. b.Tray_Type to bit, or use a computed column to determine the flag) it would run faster because you don't have to use Case statements to determine the flag. You can just add it as another column for your query.

Hope this helps! :)

Ann